# I wish to solve the differential equation: dx/dt = Ax(1-x) +(at^2 +bt +c) where A, a,b,c are constants.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation $x'=Ax(1-x)+at^2+bt+c$ is in Riccati form and reduces by the usual transformation $x=Au'/u$ to $u''-Au'+(c_0+c_1t+c_2t^2)u=0$ where $A,a,b,c,c0,c1,c2$ are constants.

Now, how does one solve this second order equation in $u$?
I tried Laplace transforms, but the equation is equally complicated: a second order differential equation in the transform of $u.$ Any ideas on solving either of these equations? I tried the power series method, with $x(t)=\sum{a_nt}^n,$ but it results again in a complicated second-order differential equation in the $Z$-transform or generating function of the coefficients $a_n.$
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: In general, Riccati DEs cannot be solved in closed form.  Maple's solution here is in terms of hypergemetric ${}_1F_1$ functions.

Comment: Seems unhandable if you don't give any relations between the constants or set some values. This is the WolframAlpha [output](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%28x%29%3Day%27%28x%29+%2B+%28b*x%5E2%2Bc*x%2Bd%29y%28x%29).